# cakephp model class extends base class then appmodel

Tags: cakephp, orm, base-class, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to setup a simple ORM for cakephp so I want to do this

App::import('Model','TheBaseModel');

class YourModel extends TheBaseModel {

}

class TheBaseModel extends AppModel {

function OptionSetter() {

}

}

But I want to put TheBaseModel in a DB folder under model (app/model/DB). How can I do this.  I am using cakephp 2.x

Comment: I'm really curious why you need to squeeze in yet another parent class? AppModel isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

put this under `plugin` and use it as a plugin.